# Check if a Driver is Loaded on Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, driver

I'm effectively trying to implement the following PowerShell function:

```
# Checks for the presence of a loaded driver.
function Check-Driver($Driver) {
    ...
}
```

I've looked around and haven't found a good way to do this. If I had a kernel debugger attached, I could just run `lm` to see everything, but I want to automate something for our CI to validate things are set up in the correct state. I have come up with one way (below) using `verifier.exe` but I don't like having to change the state of the system just to check this.

```
# Checks for the presence of a loaded driver.
function Check-Driver($Driver) {
    $Found = $false
    try {
        $Start = verifier.exe /volatile /adddriver $Driver
        $Stop = verifier.exe /volatile /removedriver $Driver
        $Found = $Stop.Contains("An instance of the service is already running")
    } catch { }
    $Found
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you want `Get-WindowsDriver -Online -Driver <path-to-driver-manifest.inf>` (or `Get-WindowsDriver -Online -All |Where Driver -like driver-manifest.inf`)

Comment: That only returns drivers installed with an inf, and not simple driver services. For instance, `http.sys` is not returned in that list, but is definitely a loaded driver on the system.

Comment: The old Service Control Manager cli can list drivers too: `sc.exe queryex http`

Comment: I found driverquery, but it doesn't use the file name (i.e. http.sys). I also found https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/driverview.html which seems to do what I need, but it's not inbox, and I don't want to take a dependency on an outside tool.

Comment: Yeah, but `sc.exe` only works on the service name, which assumes there is one and you know it. I need a generic `Check-Driver driver.sys`

Comment: Ah, apparently driverquery /v gives the file name. I can use that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that `driverquery /v` includes the full file path, so I can use that to match on file name.

```
# Checks for the presence of a loaded driver.
function Check-Driver($Driver) {
    $Found = $false
    try {
        $Found = (driverquery /v | Select-String $Driver).Matches[0].Success
    } catch { }
    $Found
}
```